# Oracle with Sworm node.js ORM TypeError: value.save is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am using the sworm javascript library to connect to an oracle database and insert data.

I am able to establish a connection and build an object to save to the database.

But, when I invoke the insert() method to insert the data, I receive the following error:

TypeError: value.save is not a function
at saveManyToOne (.........\node_modules\sworm\index.js:224:18)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I was inadvertently passing an object, instead of a primitive, as a value of a field to be stored.

Apparently, when that type of data is encountered, sworm tries to call save() on it.

Thanks